# WKWebview position fixed moves - cordova app

Tags: ios, cordova, wkwebview

Hello i have a cordova app and changed from UIWebView to WKWebview and the fixed footer moves when text overflows the view, the footer should work like in the first picture.

have tried everything i have seen, but nothing seems to work

```
#footer {
position: fixed;
bottom: 0;
background: #ffb81c;
color: white;
width: 100%;
text-align: center;
z-index: 999;
}
```

[pictures](https://i.stack.imgur.com/zNpr5.png)

Answer (score 0):

When moving one of our older apps to WKWebview, we found using the [cordova-plugin-statusbar](https://github.com/apache/cordova-plugin-statusbar) plugin in conjunction with adding the `viewport-fit=cover` attribute to the HTML viewport meta tag resolved our header and footer issues, which had an identical appearance to the example in your screenshot.

Example of the meta tag in the HTML5 `<head>` section:

`<meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, height=device-height, user-scalable=no, initial-scale=1, maximum-scale=1, minimum-scale=1, viewport-fit=cover" />`

We also appreciated being able to color match to our app's scheme in config.xml settings for the statusbar plugin, so would recommend use of this plugin anyway to improve the look of a Cordova app.

Comment: it didnt work for me, im using status bar already and if i copy and replace that meta tag in is looking like in the second picture.if in the body i set a height and put a overflow: scroll and that did it, but there is another problem, now is the rubberband when i scroll... btw i forgot to mentions all this problems are only present in ios.

Comment: i did it the way you told me, but when the keyboard is out, the header dissapears and there is no way to bring it, this is only happening with the viewport-fit=cover and wkwebview